# match.regex syntax with digit character and a #

Tags: c#, string

i have a string with this format :

```
111111#1
```

the number of digit character is 5 or 6 and   after that i set a '#' and also set a digit charcter.

i use Regex.IsMatch like this :

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(string, @"^d{6}#\d{1}"))
{...}
```

but it cant handle my string
what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This single line Regex will capture two groups: the leading five to six digits and the '#' followed by a single digit:

```
(\d{5,6})(#\d{1})
```

Example:

```
string pattern = @"(\d{5,6})(#\d{1})";
string input = "111111#1";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
  var firstGroupValue = match.Groups[1]; // "111111"
  var secondGroupValue = match.Groups[2]; // "#1"
}
```

Comment: Why talk about groups here, this was not in the question... could confuse some just looking for the answer.

Comment: This is not confusing. First the fixed/improved expression. Then followed by an example which is also titled 'Example'.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the backslash on the first `d` so it's not matching against digits:

`Regex.IsMatch("111111#1", @"^\d{6}#\d{1}")`